# Cannot subtract from 1 single item?

Tags: java, bukkit

I have setup this method where players can use Gunpowder when they Right-Click to cloak for some second, and 1 Gunpowder will be subtracted from their inventory. The problem is that, when they are left with only 1 Gunpowder, it will not get subtracted as a result they will have infinite cloak. Here is my code:

```
if (e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR)
        || e.getAction().equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
    if (e.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInHand().getType()
            .equals(Material.SULPHUR)) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();

        Location location = e.getPlayer().getLocation().add(new Vector(0, 2, 0));

        Bukkit.getWorld(e.getPlayer().getWorld().getName())
                .createExplosion(location, 0);

        player.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.INVISIBILITY, 80, 0));

        player.getItemInHand().setAmount(player.getItemInHand().getAmount() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `==` for enums (`Material` and `Action`).

Comment: Use `player.getWorld()` instead of `Bukkit.getWorld(e.getPlayer().getWorld().getName())`.

Comment: Use `player.getItemInHand()` instead of `e.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInHand()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is here.

```
player.getItemInHand().setAmount(player.getItemInHand().getAmount() - 1);
```

`ItemStack.setAmount(0)` will fail.

---

Review your entire algorithm.

```
ItemStack hand = player.getItemInHand();
int amount = hand.getAmount();
if (amount > 1) {
    hand.setAmount(amount - 1);
    player.setItemInHand(hand);
} else {
    player.setItemInHand(new ItemStack(Material.AIR));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be removing items instead of setting their amount.

```
ItemStack remove = new ItemStack(Material.SULPHUR, 1);
player.getInventory().removeItem(remove);
```

That should remove 1 gunpowder from their inventory.